# How to integrate socket.io to the mvc architecture of my express project

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am making a backend with socket.io and express, however I cannot connect the sockets with my frontend with nextjs, when entering a page a fetch is executed that connects with the web sockets through an endpoint, the controller works because I receive the response however the sockets do not respond, if someone could guide me I would appreciate it, I am new to this.

index.js

```
app.use('/items', itemsRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is runnig on port http://localhost:3001')
})
```

router.js

```
export const itemsRouter = Router()

itemsRouter.get('/', ItemController.getAll)
itemsRouter.post('/', ItemController.create)
itemsRouter.post('/api/data', ItemController.getData)
```

controller.js

```
export class ItemController {
  static getData = async (req, res) => {
    io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
      console.log('an user has connected')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to implement with web sockets? The socket listener is not usually setup via a route/controller, the web socket is normally an alternate way to initiate a controller, rather than using a http route.

Comment: @Matt Hello, thanks for the answer, I am creating an API and also a communication bridge with an Arduino board and I do this through web sockets, however I am not sure where to initialize it, I have not found many examples of this on the internet , the controller constructor does not seem like a good option to me since in the routes. js file I am creating multiple instances.

Comment: Here is the [express example socket.io provide](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/#with-express). Notice how `io` is adjacent to the `app`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the provided server updated with the [socket.io server example](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/#with-express) and one socket event handler.

```
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const app = express()

app.use('/items', itemsRouter)

const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, { /* options */ });

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  console.log('an user has connected', socket.id)
  socket.on('apiData', ItemController.getDataSocket)
})
```

The express/http router stays the same.

I've added the equivalent socket.io and express request/response controllers next to each other to demonstrate the differences in their signature.

```
export class ItemController {
  static getDataExpress = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body
    const data = await someFetch(id)
    res.json({ data })
  }
  static getDataSocket = async(payload, callback) => {
    const { id } = payload
    const data = await someFetch(id)
    callback({ data })
  }
}
```

Usually sockets are more useful for their streaming and broadcasting rather than request/response pattern that express is already capable of. Often you will want to trigger sockets from routes so you usually want to attach the `io` instance to requests.

Add the `io` instance to the `app` in index.js

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
  req.app.set('io', io)
})
```

An example of this is broadcasting a new item, to the interested clients that have joined the `items` [room](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/).

```
export class ItemController {
  static newItem = async (req, res) => {
    const { item } = req.body
    const data = await creatItem(item)
    req.app.get('io).to("items").emit('newItem', item)
    res.json({ item })
  }
}
```